# Node object doesn't exist when not logged in

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I am trying to use the preprocess_page hook to add some twig variables.

All worked fine, until I logged out. When I'm logged out, the hooks $variables does not contain a node object.

Sample code:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['hero_image'] = '';

  if (!empty($variables['node'])) {
    $node = $variables['node']; // if logged in, this is set, logged out, it's not
    // other code here...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should check the anonymous user permisions 
www.yourwebsite.com/admin/people/permissions/anonymous

Comment: This was exactly it. I hate Drupal sometimes...

Comment: @MrPablo : I don't get it ... how can ***you*** know what exactly "it was" that caused the issue as described in the question here ... by user [Paul Canning](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/76608/paul-canning) ... unless of course that is your user id "also" ...

Comment: I have two accounts